# Constant curvature riemann manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

So, I am studying cosmology, and while investing the math involved with the assumptions regarding the metric used (isotropic and homogeneous), I stumbled upon a definition that was recurring, that of a constant curvature manifold (don't know if it's the right terminology).

If I'm not mistaken, the definition is any manifold such that it's riemann tensor has the following form :

$$ R_{abcd} = K(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$$

We notice that for a riemann tensor of this form, the Ricci scalar is indeed constant and proportional to K.

My question is : is the definition of a constant curvature manifold (or whatever the right object is, if I remember correctly a manifold isn't necessarily endowed with a metric) the one I gave on $R_{abcd}$ ?

It would be more intuitive for me if constant curvature was simply a manifold with constant Ricci scalar. If this is indeed the definition, is there an easy way to prove the general form of $R_{abcd}$ ?

Comment: As Andrew D. Hwang points out, constant curvature means constant sectional curvature. This implies the Riemann curvature tensor takes the form you stated. To see this, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222171/39599).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your setting, "constant curvature" means *constant [sectional curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature)*. The usual definition is "every tangent $2$-plane has the same curvature"; the formula you give for the Riemann curvature tensor is then a theorem.

In differential geometry, a metric with constant Ricci curvature is usually called an *[Einstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_manifold)*.

Being Einstein is not equivalent to having constant curvature. Up to overall scaling, there are precisely three local models for a [space of constant curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_curvature) (and three complete, simply-connected examples: the sphere, Euclidean space, and hyperbolic space). By contrast, there are moduli spaces of Einstein metrics even on a single smooth manifold. For example, the [smooth $4$-manifold underlying a complex quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface) in complex projective $3$-space admits, up to scaling, a [$20$-dimensional family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface#The_period_map) of [Ricci-flat Kähler metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) by Yau's solution of the [Calabi conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi_conjecture).

Comment: Being Einstein for a pseudo riemannian manifold doesn't precisely mean that the Ricci tensor is constant, it means that is proportional (when $dimM\geq4$) to the metric as a $(0,2)$ tensor.